# String to Date Parse Exception with FastDateFormat

Tags: java, date, type-conversion

I want to parse a `String` to `Date` object via `FastDateFormat`.

`simpleDateStr` is `"04/13/2017"` Here is my code:

```
private static final String SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";

(Date) FastDateFormat.getInstance(SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT).parseObject(simpleDateStr);
```

I get that exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Format.parseObject(String) failed
    at java.text.Format.parseObject(Format.java:245)
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try using `parse(simpleDateStr)` instead of `parseObject(simpleDateStr)`, then you also won't need to cast the result to the type `Date`.

Comment: Works fine for me (both `parse` and `parseObject`), so I guess it is time to create a [mcve]. Make sure that `simpleDateStr` is ___really___ "04/13/2017" and doesn't contain any hidden bytes.

Comment: OK. I found it. I just realised that I was using 2.6. It has a bug and switching to 3.6 fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that 2.6 has a bug and switching to 3.6 fixed the problem.

**PS:** Reason is it is not implemented as @Shekhar Khairnar answered.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.6 implementation(straight from the source code of FastDateFormat) is like:

```
// Parsing
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * <p>Parsing is not supported.</p>
     * 
     * @param source  the string to parse
     * @param pos  the parsing position
     * @return <code>null</code> as not supported
     */
    public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        pos.setIndex(0);
        pos.setErrorIndex(0);
        return null;
    }
```

this is the culprit